# Use typedef member from a template class outside of the class as return type for member function

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, member

What should i put instead of three question marks?

```
template <class T>
class B_T
{
public:
    typedef _Array_iterator<T, uint32> iterator;

    iterator begin();
};

template <class T>
??? B_T<T>::begin()
{
    // code here
}
```

Comment: Is this your own code? Because then you should be aware of [the rules regarding leading underscore in names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg _Array_iterator is part of std library here. In real codeit is prefixed with `std::`, sorry for misleading.

Comment: You should be careful when using internal classes of a specific standard library implementation, as that makes your code unportable. It might even cause problems if you upgrade your compiler/standard library to a newer version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
template <class T>
typename B_T<T>::iterator B_T<T>::begin()
{
    // code here
}
```

The `typename` keyword is needed because `iterator` is depending on a template parameter, as well resumed on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) SO answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T>
typename B_T<T>::iterator B_T<T>::begin();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several choices:

```
template <class T>
_Array_iterator<T, uint32> B_T<T>::begin() {/**/}
```

but why using `typedef` in that case ;-)
else the classical way:

```
template <class T>
typename B_T<T>::iterator B_T<T>::begin() {/**/}
```

and since C++11:

```
template <class T>
auto B_T<T>::begin() -> iterator {/**/} // No need of `typename B_T<T>::` before `iterator`.
```